# Odd behavior with SSRS and table spacing on a new page

Tags: reporting-services

In my report in SSRS, I have about .2 inches of space between the headers and tables. However, I have an issue where I have a table that is multiple pages long, and there ends up being no space between the table and the next row on the new page, like so:

[image]

And this is what my report likes in the viewer. Note that my .2 inches of white space is inside each subreport.
[image]
[image]
Is there anything to be done about this?

Comment: Is it an actual header in the report itself? or a row header in the tablix?

Comment: Yes, the gold bar is an actual header. I have a large single cell "table" that takes up the rest of the space so I can give appropriate context to the subreports, and inside the single cell "table" is all of the subreports and such. The single cell "table" is right up against the header--all the spacing is done inside of the single cell table.

Answer (score 2):

If moving the subreports a few pixels away from the tablix doesn't help, I like to add another row to the bottom of the tablix and set the **BorderStyle** to **None** for the extra row in the text box properties. This forces spacing between elements and is not visible in the rendered report.

Comment: Each subreport has .2 inches of while space on top inside the subreport, and that is why there is normally good spacing. It is just in the instance where a table gets broken up on to different pages where no white space occurs.

Comment: Did you try adding the additional row right before your page break group? By that I mean: try adding the row immediately after the group that you're page breaking on, if you have that property set.

Comment: In the attempt to be simple I only mentioned one report. However, the table that gets broken up varies, each table is variable length, and I have a couple different reports that this is happening in.

Comment: Does it get broken up in a specific pattern? For example, if I have a list of cars in my tablix and I want to group by make, are you putting each make on a separate page?

Comment: No, there is no pattern.

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted the picture. Have you also tried putting an additional hidden row at the top of the tablix (or above the group)?

Comment: It could be my ignorance, but I am not sure that would help as the rows are being split up by a new page. One table could be two pages long, and every time a new page starts, the next row will be right underneath the header (no white space), instead of showing the desired white space.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include how you have your page breaks set up? That might help.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this--I just put the .2in space space in the header instead of the body.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have margins set on the report output. Make sure  you have a top margin set in:

**Report Properties** > **Margins**